# Determining that form is alive

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, firemonkey

Im have method of the form which loads the data, some data may take a long time to load. This part of data is optional and form can be closed before this data is loaded:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadData(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Load and add data to the form
  ...
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
    // Long data loading
    ...
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
    begin
      // Add data to the form
      ...
    end);
  end).Start;
end;
```

And the question: which is best method to determine that form is alive (not closed) for FMX to avoid exception when data from thread should be added? Long loading I mean not hours or ten's minutes, this can be up to one minute.

Update: after closing form I don't need additional data anymore and thread can be terminated. This is will be terminated in any way, but I neet to do it without exception. Currently I have

```
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
    begin
      // Add data to the form
      try
        ...
      except
      end;
    end);
```

and this is works, but I search decision without exception

Comment: No any comments, 11 views and -2 votes - this is very simple question or wrong realization?

Comment: Don't allow the form to be closed while the thread is running. Or don't access the form from the thread (which means running it without it calling Synchronize). You can't have it both ways. If you stand on the branch that you're cutting off the tree, you have no control over what happens when the saw goes through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one of possible decisions:

Add to the form:

```
  protected
    FThread: TThread;
```

Changed loading method:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadData(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Load and add data to the form
  ...
  FThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
    // Long data loading
    ...
    if not TThread.Current.CheckTerminated then
      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
      begin
        // Add data to the form
        ...
      end);
  end);
  FThread.Start;
end;
```

And in Form.OnClose:

```
  if not FThread.ExternalThread then
    FThread.Terminate;
```

Thread is moved to the ExternalThreads list (internally by Delphi) when we call TThread.Current method and this mean that it is already sent TThread.Synchronize part of code. Will be glad to see any additional comments when you vote for this answer.

Comment: With Anonymous thread I can put loading code in one procedure and this is more useful to view and check this, previously this part was in TThread class (on the Delphi 5)